# Partition an unmanaged byte array into "typed fields" in .Net 4.7

Tags: .net, interop, unmanaged

In .Net, say I have an unmanaged array of bytes that represents a storage page. I have an `IntPtr` to each array. Now I want to partition the array into "fields".

The code below illustrates what I mean, but it throws an exception and I don't know why.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 1024 * 4)]
internal unsafe struct Page
{
    // the actual byte array
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public fixed byte buffer[1024 * 4];

    [FieldOffset(1024 * 0)]
    public fixed byte header[1024];

    [FieldOffset(1024 * 1)]
    public fixed byte block1[1024];

    [FieldOffset(1024 * 2)]
    public fixed byte block2[1024];

    [FieldOffset(1024 * 3)]
    public fixed byte block3[1024];
}

private unsafe void test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr p = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(GCHandle.Alloc(new Page(), GCHandleType.Pinned));
    Page* page = (Page*)p;

    page->block1[0] = 1;    // << works
    page->block2[0] = 2;    // << works
    page->block3[0] = 3;    // << System.AccessViolationException

    if (page->buffer[1024] == 1
        && page->buffer[1024*2] == 2 
    //  && page->buffer[1024*3] == 3
    )
    {
        MessageBox.Show("OK");
    }

    GCHandle.FromIntPtr(p).Free();
}
```

What is the correct way to do this? What I am trying to achieve is to offset block1 etc. to the correct pointers. So looking at my example, if `p` points to the 4,096 byte array, then `page->header` should `= p`, `page->block1` should `= p + 1024`, etc.

Comment: Strange it works for you. Overlapping is legal. It's often used in casting. Nonetheless, what I am trying to achieve is to offset block1 etc. to the correct pointers.

Comment: I found the error. `Page* page = (Page*)p;` should be `Page* page = (Page*)&p;`

Comment: No, that just randomly moves the pointer to a place where it doesn't wreak as much havoc on the .NET run-time. You need to be careful with unsafe code :) `p` is already a pointer. By doing `&p`, you take the pointer *to the variable p*. That has nothing to do with your `Page` object! It just means you're writing to stack space, which is less likely to break things.

Comment: Thanks much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GCHandle.ToIntPtr` is not the pointer to the `Page` object. It's just the GC handle represented as an integer (e.g. to allow you to easily pass a "pseudo-reference" to the handle to unamanged code and back again). You're randomly writing to memory :)

You need to use `GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject` to actually get the `Page` object's address.

Also, for most scenarios, `GCHandle` is an overkill. If you can contain the pinning to a scope, it's better to use a `fixed` block instead.

Finally, just to keep this out of the comments: `fixed byte` is just a byte pointer, not a managed array. You don't gain much by overlapping the fields; it's equivalent to just taking a pointer to an element in the array (e.g. `block2 == &buffer[1024*2]`). In the case of large byte buffers, there probably isn't much extra danger either, though - I'll need to go through the specs to check if it's legal or not :)

Comment: I have to keep the objects pinned for the app's lifecycle. What I need isn't possible with `fixed` (which I usually use under less rigorous requirements).

Comment: So as such, right? `var h = GCHandle.Alloc(new Page(), GCHandleType.Pinned); IntPtr p = h.AddrOfPinnedObject(); Page* page = (Page*)&p;` How do I free this?

Comment: @IamIC If you need them pinned for the app's life-cycle, are you sure using managed memory in the first place is a good idea? It does complicate the GC's job somewhat, for almost no reason.

Comment: Ordinarily, I would stick with managed code. I'm working on a prototype that will be using memory mapped files, which require unmanaged code. Again, I can't simply use `using` because the app will serve data on demand.

Comment: @IamIC Don't take the pointer to `p`, that's just the address of the variable. And pay attention to taking the handle to `new Page` - it's a value-type, so you're really taking a `GCHandle` to *another* object created on the heap. If you're allocating the `Page` objects in an array or something, `GCHandle.Alloc(allPages[123])` will *not* give you the `&allPages[123]` pointer.

Comment: Sorry, @Luaan, like this?: `var h = GCHandle.Alloc(new Page(), GCHandleType.Pinned); IntPtr p = h.AddrOfPinnedObject(); Page* page = (Page*)p; ... h.Free()'`

Comment: Gosh, C is so much simpler!

Comment: @IamIC Yes, that's incorrect. You want to do `(Page*)p` instead.

Comment: @IamIC Well, you can use C# almost exactly the same as C if you want. If you only use unmanaged memory, it will really be very similar (the main difference being far fewer undefined behaviours in C#).

Comment: I'm used to Delphi. Very straightforward. C of course doesn't have the GC pros & cons.

Comment: @IamIC Some of the people who worked on Delphi went on to develop C# :P Some things ended up working better, others worse (the same with VB.NET). Delphi doesn't have a GC either, mind you - that's why some things appear more straightforward. But again, if you want more old-school coding, use only unmanaged memory and the stack, and the code is almost identical to both C and Delphi :)

Comment: Anders Hejlsberg is a genius, for sure. Delphi has a partial GC (strings are managed, for e.g.). But I found the pointers in Delphi to be very simple. Same in C. But C#... very complex!

Comment: @IamIC I never felt that way - pointers work almost the same way in C# as they do in C (Delphi has a few tricks extra). Perhaps it's just that in C#, pointers are a lot more rare in general. In C/Delphi, most of the time you needed to pass a big object anywhere or allocate anything dynamically, you'd need to use pointers. In C#, pointers are only used for interop and low-level optimisations. Of course, things get more complicated if you need to work with pointers in managed memory - but that's just due to breaking some of the convenient abstractions in .NET. And function names are longer :)

Comment: I think we agree. Only in C# do we have the extra layers of GC, pinning, converting pointers. I mean, look at my initial code. It "worked" but was actually wrong. How can I write and read to memory, get the correct results, yet have an incorrect pointer? Only in C# ;)

Comment: @IamIC You'd have the exact same problem in C, you just wouldn't notice it anywhere near as fast. It's not like C prevents you from writing to random valid addresses in memory :D If you took the result of `malloc` and did the exact same operation, it likely wouldn't fail (in DOS) even if `malloc` returned a null-pointer, for example. If you took the pointer to the variable you used to store the result of `malloc`, you'd have the same problem etc. But really, in this case, you can avoid managed memory and the GC entirely - just keep a pointer somewhere, like you would in C.

Comment: @IamIC The only case where it would be significantly simpler would be if you used a statically-allocated array in the C code. There's no way to do the same thing in C#, since there isn't any static allocation, really, and no global mutable variables. But if you do the closest thing in C# and put `Page[]` in a field, all you need to do is `fixed (Page *page = &pages[123])` to get a pointer to page 124. You're just taking a particularly windy detour instead of doing the simple thing :D

Comment: That wouldn't make it easy to dynamically allocate and free pages, though. I'm using a managed dictionary of page ID & handle.

Comment: @IamIC I'm still not sure why you'd need the handle. Why not take the pointer whenever you need it, rather than pinning the memory for the entire life-time of the application? A dictionary of page ID -> `byte[]` sounds a lot more reasonable. It's not like a dictionary gives you nice memory organisation or thread-safety. Of course, making an efficient page-management and memory-management system isn't entirely trivial; but you have many options that might work great for you.

Comment: I guess it seems more efficient to pin the pages that are alive rather than having the GC shuffling them around, plus having the overhead of having to pin and unpin pages on demand. I mean, C / C++ etc. don't shuffle things around. I'm not aware that I'm losing anything with this approach. Ps. I altered my code to return the pointer, not the handle. The handle is still stored as it's needed to free the objects.

Comment: @IamIC, `Ordinarily, I would stick with managed code. I'm working on a prototype that will be using memory mapped files, which require unmanaged code.` - I hope that this does not mean that you believe that .Net does not support MMFs.  [Memory-Mapped Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files)

Comment: I know it does. This is a prototype. Right now, I'm examining my options. :)

Comment: @IamIC The thing is, .NET always allocates memory on top of the heap. That's why .NET allocations are so cheap. But it also means that any gaps in the memory are completely unusable until the heap can be compacted. If your object prevents the heap from being compacted, *too bad* - you just killed the GC. I've had services run out of memory with 16 GiB committed memory while the actual memory used was less than 200 MiB, and that's after the GC started separating the memory into hundreds of heaps. Get rid of all your assumptions, they're worthless, *especially* with regards to memory management.

Comment: @IamIC While C++ *usually* doesn't shuffle memory around, it also has a much higher cost when allocating any new memory. There's very little overhead to pinning and unpinning memory - much less than for keeping memory pinned forever. If you need to pin memory for a long time, keep it on the LOH or keep it unmanaged. You're preventing the GC from working well. And every single GCHandle you create is an extra overhead as well, since GCHandles are kept in a map (that's how `GCHandle.FromIntPtr` works), not to mention you keep track of it yourself.

Comment: @IamIC What *seems* efficient and what *actually is* efficient is rarely the same thing even without managed memory. In the end, you rarely get a good idea until you test in a realistic scenario, and sometimes only when you get things to production. Take a look at the tricks StackOverflow uses to actually work well - and see how many seem like good ideas, good practices or intuitive. With Delphi/C intuitions, some will feel entirely obvious, while others seem entirely ridiculous :P

Comment: I agree with you. As I said, I'm prototyping. I will test fully managed too. I just needed to know what I was doing wrong with my unmanaged code. You have been very helpful and I will take your further advice.

Comment: I wrote some inter-thread priority queues a few years ago. They are faster than Disruptor. The key was to throw intuitive away. In many ways, the most efficient approach is often in the unthinkable realm.